# How to use "Group by" LINQ?

Tags: c#, excel, linq, group-by, where-clause

i use Linq with DataSet for excel multi sheet. 
How to use Group by LINQ?

**Sample Data:**

```
Name        | Rate | Date       | Code | ROW_SEQ
A           | 12   | 01/01/2015 | 12   | 1
B           | 13   | 01/01/2015 | 12   | 2
Sub Total   | 25   | 01/01/2015 | 12   | 
C           | 10   | 01/01/2015 | 12   | 3
Grand Total | 35   | 01/01/2015 | 12   | 
D           | 15   | 10/01/2015 | 15   | 1
E           | 16   | 10/01/2015 | 15   | 2
Sub Total   | 31   | 10/01/2015 | 15   | 
F           | 10   | 10/01/2015 | 15   | 3
Grand Total | 41   | 10/01/2015 | 15   |
```

**C# Code:**

```
protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{              
    /*== How to use Group by LINQ? ==*/
    DataSet dsTmp = new DataSet();
    DataTable dtTmp = dtExport.Copy();
    var grouped = from table in dtTmp.AsEnumerable()
        group table by new { date_Col = table["date"] , code_Col = table["code"] } into groupby
        select new
        {
            Value = groupby.Key,
            ColumnValues = groupby
        };
    /*== How to use Group by LINQ? ==*/

    foreach (var key in grouped)
    {
        dtTmp = new DataTable();
        dtTmp = dtExport.Clone();
        dtTmp.TableName = (key.Value.settle_date_Col + "-" + key.Value.bank_code_Col).Replace("00:00:00", "").Replace("/","");
        foreach (var rw in key.ColumnValues)
        {
            dtTmp.ImportRow(rw);
        }
        dtTmp.AcceptChanges();
        dsTmp.Tables.Add(dtTmp.Copy());
    }
    dsTmp.AcceptChanges(); 
    string fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.xls", this._ID, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"));
    ExcelMultiSheet.ToExcel(dsTmp, fileName, Page.Response);          

}
```

**Code Results:**

```
Sheet1
Name        | Rate | Date       | Code | ROW_SEQ
A           | 12   | 01/01/2015 | 12   | 1
B           | 13   | 01/01/2015 | 12   | 2
C           | 10   | 01/01/2015 | 12   | 3

Sheet2
Name        | Rate | Date       | Code | ROW_SEQ
Sub Total   | 25   | 01/01/2015 | 12   |
Grand Total | 35   | 01/01/2015 | 12   |

Sheet3
Name        | Rate | Date       | Code | ROW_SEQ
D           | 15   | 10/01/2015 | 15   | 1
E           | 16   | 10/01/2015 | 15   | 2 
F           | 10   | 10/01/2015 | 15   | 3

Sheet4
Name        | Rate | Date       | Code | ROW_SEQ
Sub Total   | 31   | 10/01/2015 | 15   |
Grand Total | 41   | 10/01/2015 | 15   |
```

**But i need Results:**

```
Sheet1
    Name        | Rate | Date       | Code | ROW_SEQ
    A           | 12   | 01/01/2015 | 12   | 1
    B           | 13   | 01/01/2015 | 12   | 2
    Sub Total   | 25   | 01/01/2015 | 12   |
    C           | 10   | 01/01/2015 | 12   | 3
    Grand Total | 35   | 01/01/2015 | 12   |

Sheet2
    Name        | Rate | Date       | Code | ROW_SEQ
    D           | 15   | 10/01/2015 | 15   | 1
    E           | 16   | 10/01/2015 | 15   | 2
    Sub Total   | 31   | 10/01/2015 | 15   |
    F           | 10   | 10/01/2015 | 15   | 3
    Grand Total | 41   | 10/01/2015 | 15   |
```

Thanks advance. :)

Comment: Based on that data and the group by you are using you should only get two groups.  Are you sure that the sub totals and grand totals don't have different values for either the date or code?  Maybe the time portion of the dates are different?

Comment: @juhar i sure sub totals and grand totals don't have different values.

Comment: Is it possible that the types are differen?.  Maybe the sub toal and grand total rows have string values instead of `DateTime` and `int` or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
var results = from p in persons
              group p.car by p.PersonId into g
              select new { PersonID = g.Key, Cars = g.ToList() };
```